# Browser returns SSL error : Your connection is not private

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, meanjs

I did my project in MEAN stack. I have installed GeoTrust Wildcard SSL certificate. It worked very well till yesterday. From today morning onward, it returns an error : "Your connection is private".

I don't know why this error occurs suddenly in any browser while run an application. It required to adding manually in exception lists to visit site. Right now I am not able to keep going my site. Certificate having 1 year validity and it was renewed in last month.

Please review attached images.
[image]

Give me guideline to solve this issue.

Comment: If you look closely in the screenshot (i.e. read the text right after the part you redacted), you'll find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate installed has expired. Looks like you have not installed or assigned the new certificate to your website.